# How to get a report of send messages from wire2air api in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using wire2air api for sending messages I need generate report of send messages any idea how to call api for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delivery reports are only supposed for Advanced Developer account. If you are one then go to the help console there is a explanation for it there. [click me](http://www.wire2air.com/developer_apis.asp) shows that it exists in the api.

Comment: hey how should i get know my account type advance developer account or not?

Comment: @priyankaUkirde Did you pay something to purchase your membership?

Comment: @ dirtydexter which plan i have to for access advance developer api